# Vue: computed property in parent not called

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

In Vue 3 i have a problem calling a computed property. I need to show a component if a user sign in correctly.

In my App.vue i have:

```
<template>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <Sidebar v-if="authorized"/>
   </div>
   <main class="content">
        <router-view />
   </main>
</template>

<script>
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar.vue";

export default {
   name: "App",
   components: {
      Sidebar
   },
   computed: {
    authorized: () => { 
      //some code
      }
   },
 };
```

For example, when i go to /login path, the authorized computed property is called.
Then, in my Login.vue component, i have a method with:

```
 this.$router.push({ name: 'Dashboard' })
```

The problem is that after the router.push, the computed property in App vue parent isn't called.

Why?

Comment: give more details as well as computer property code

Comment: router-view is whats being rendered/changed then you call `this.$router.push` not App.vue, so is not going to re-compute authorized

Comment: use vuex (more standard), or in this file, have a state property data:()=>({state:{authorized:false}}) which you pass to the `router-view :state="state"`, then inside the page component you can change the state and it will update the parent `v-if="state.authorized"`, also can use a global eventbus, to name a few ways